# How to send command line arguments to batch file containing "=" char

Tags: batch-file

I want to invoke a batch file(tomcat's startup.bat) by passing a command line argument something like **c:>startup.bat -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true**

But the "=" symbol is being replaced with a space.
If I put c:>startup.bat -D"sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true" the value was not set properly.

I am using Windows 7.

Is there anyway to pass command line arguments containing "="?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do much about it **inside** the batch file, except change `%1` to `%1=%2`, which only works if you know exactly how many parameters you're passing in, or you know they will always come in pairs. (I suppose you could loop and put together all of the `-Dxxx` parameters with the next parameter, and put those without a leading `-D`, but if you have other `=`-style parameters it can get really messy.)

But you can do something **outside** the batch file, by putting your parameter in quotes:

```
startup "-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%*` for all parameters.

In your batch

```
@echo off
javac %*
```

Or you can enquote your complete parameter
`startup.bat "-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true"`

And startup.bat looks like (the %~1 removes surrounding quotes from %1)

```
@echo off
javac %~1
```